# Constant Speed Prop Power Settings

Tags: piston-engine, constant-speed-propeller

I'm studying the performance data for a Piper Arrow with a constant speed propeller. The rule of thumb that I've heard is not to let manifold pressure go above RPM. This performance data seems to show some configurations where this doesn't hold true. Am I reading the table correctly? And is the rule of thumb not true in this case?

[image]

Comment: For example I read the 23.7, 23.4, 23.0 etc. as MP under the RPM of 2200, under 55% power column. Is that wrong?

Comment: @MichaelHall see my clarification

Comment: Oh yeah, I wasn't interpreting it correctly...  Thx.

Comment: @Chris It does thanks. I was also specifically interested in whether I was reading the performance chart the correct way, which that question doesn't answer directly but it seems more obvious that I am now.